# how can i use only costmap_2d map? (navigation stack without base_controller)

Tags: navigation, mapping, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, currently i can create maps with gmapping + laser_scan_matcher and hector_slam.

i want to see obstacles in the map i create. so costmap is the answer i guess.

i just have lms100 laser scanner, not a robot system to control so in navigation stack, base_controler requirement is not met. so can i use a part of navigation stack which includes costmap_2d especially? if so, what is the proper way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236900/how-can-i-use-only-costmap_2d-map?-(navigation-stack-without-base_controller)/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also run the costmap_2d_node (in the costmap_2d package)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-14**:
for doing that properly, should i create and modify a launch file like example.launch (in the costmap_2d launch directory)??? is it enough for me to see obstacles in the map?